# Why these elems of navbar are not in one rows with bootstrap navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In my project, I use bootstrap.
And i use navbar with MAIN PAGE, My GOODS, SHOPPING CAR and login.

I want them in the same horizontal line, but actually, they are in different rows.

The resolution of my monitor is 1680X1050

```
 <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="" target="_self">MAIN PAGE</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"> <a href="trade.php" target="_self">My GOODS</a></li>
            <li class="active"> <a href="cart.php" target="_self">SHOPPING CAR</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li class="active">
            <a href="login.php?action=login">login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably go through [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) to see how its properly done.

regardless, using your code, add `navbar-expand-sm` to the container and `navbar-nav` to the inner div.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
    <div class="navbar-inner navbar-nav">
        <a class="brand" href="" target="_self">MAIN PAGE</a>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"> <a href="trade.php" target="_self">My GOODS</a></li>
            <li class="active"> <a href="cart.php" target="_self">SHOPPING CAR</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li class="active">
            <a href="login.php?action=login">login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.bootply.com/xufZyDyeiK